# Batch File to move subfolder contents from mapped location to Server

Tags: file, batch-file, move, subdirectory

I want to write a batch file to move all the content from mapped location to the server

ODM folder is already there on the server.
I tried both the code:

```
robocopy "\\eng1\d$\ODM" "\\200.200.200.9\c$\ODM" /s /z /move /mt:96 /log:C:\Temp\log.txt
```

and

```
xcopy /-y \\eng1\d$\ODM\*.* \\200.200.200.9\C$\ODM\ /d /c /y  
pause
```

I am getting errors as

> Invalid username or password for first code and 
>   Invalid Drive specification for second

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Invalid UNC path - `\\200.` not `\200.` and remove the `:` after the `C$` admin share.  `-Y` and `Y` are contradictory.  You may need a `*.*` wildcard in the source path as well.

Comment: @Alex: there were two backslashes - they were just not shown because of missing formatting. `*.*` is default, when no other mask is given.

Comment: You might want to assing drive letters to both paths (`net use`), supplying usernames and passwords first, then use those "drives" as source and destination.

Comment: how to provide username and password?

Comment: [net use /?](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html)

Comment: `net use \\eng1\IPC$ /user:domain\user password`

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `net use` as also mentioned by Stephan in the comments above, to ensure it has a connection to both UNC paths, each time using username and password. (Remove `domain\` if you do not use domain.

```
net use \\eng1\IPC$ /user:domain\user password
net use \\200.200.200.9\IPC$ /user:domain\user password
robocopy "\\eng1\d$\ODM" "\\200.200.200.9\c$\ODM" /s /z /move /mt:96 /log:C:\Temp\log.txt
```

Comment: You mean the mapped location(source) needs to be connected to the server(destination)?

Comment: Tried with following command but getting error as ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory \\200.200.200.9\c$\ODM\
Access is denied.

net use \\200.200.200.9\IPC$ /user:<domain>\<user> <pwd>
robocopy "C:\Temp\ODM" "\\200.200.200.9\c$\ODM" /MOVE /E /R:2 /TEE /LOG:C:\temp\movelog.txt

Comment: So then your user does not have the relevant access.